# Regex to check to find out items with given character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a class

```
public class MyClass
        {
            public MyClass(int id, string name)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                //Id = id;
                this.Name = name;
            }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

I created a list of MyClass type and added few items to it

```
    List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
    lst.Add(new MyClass(1, "Name1"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(2, "ab****cdefg"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(3, "he*llo"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(4, "pa**yed"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(5, "Names2"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(6, "hi******iiii"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(7, "so*me"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(8, "so**rt"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(9, "*"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(10, "**"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(11, "t*e*s*t"));
    lst.Add(new MyClass(12, "t**e**s**t"));
```

How can i find items having only one `*` in name field in a list and two `**` in name field in another list. I'ld like to do it by linq or regex, any other good option is also invited. I tried using `contains` method but got all items having `*`.

```
var singlestar = lst.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("*")).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you want a list of `int`s representing IDs that matched both lists' criteria?

Comment: no i want list of `MyClass`

Comment: that doesn't really make sense.  You'll have 2 `MyClass` with different `Name`s, one with 1 `*` and one with 2 `*`.  Which `MyClass` do you want

Comment: @Jonesy : i want both in two different list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should match names with just one "\*" and two "\*\*"

```
var singlestar = lst.Where(x =>Regex.Matches(x.Name,  "\\*").Count == 1).ToList();
var twostar = lst.Where(x =>Regex.Matches(x.Name,  "\\*\\*").Count == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for solution of 1 star it works, i figured it out for two `**` but can u please explain in your answer what does `.Count == 1` does.

Comment: @SidM the regular expression matches *. so this counts the matches within one string.

Comment: Note that this doesn't correctly handle things like `"abc*defg*"`. I don't know if the OP needs to identify those, but your code won't identify that as containing a single "*".

Answer (score 0):

If you only need single stars I suspect those shouldn't contain at least 2 stars. If stars might show up elsewhere a regex might be better.

```
var singlestar = lst.Where(x => (x.Name.Contains("*") and !(x.Name.Contains("**")))).ToList();

var doublestar = lst.Where(x => (x.Name.Contains("**") and !(x.Name.Contains("***")))).ToList();
```

Or with Regex

```
Regex rgx1 = new Regex(@"^[^*]*\\*[^*]*$");
Regex rgx2 = new Regex(@"^[^*]*\\*\\*[^*]*$");
var singlestar = lst.Where(x => rgx1.IsMatch(x.Name)).ToList();

var doublestar = lst.Where(x => rgx2.IsMatch(x.Name)).ToList();
```

With the Regex, there should be no other stars anywhere else in the name.

Comment: 1) i want two different list 
2) there can be any number of * in name

Comment: What should the second list contain, only two? The first list accounts for two or more.